# How to number a lemma between Lemma 1 and Lemma 2?

Tags: theorems

During a revision of a paper, I need to insert a lemma after Lemma 1 and before Lemma 2. I do not want to call it "Lemma 2", because the previous Lemma 2 would change to Lemma 3, the previous Lemma 3 would change to Lemma 4, etc., and this would confuse the reviewers. So, at least for the review, I would like to call the new lemma something like "Lemma 1*" or "Lemma 1.5" or "Lemma 1a" or something like this. I tried to change the counter using `\setcounter{lemma}{1.5}` but it did not work.

Is there a way to do this using the lemma environment? (if possible, I would like to be able to also use a `\label` in this lemma, so that I can later refer to it with `\ref`).

Comment: Incidentally, which document class do you employ, and which packages (if any) do you use to set up theorem-like environments?

Comment: I use a specialized journal document class, and the `amsthm` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This assumes that lemmas have their own counter

```
\let\savedthelemma\thelemma
\edef\thelemma{\thelemma.5}
\begin{lemma}\label{newlemma}
This is the added lemma.
\end{lemma}
\let\thelemma\savedthelemma
\addtocounter{lemma}{-1}
```

Of course you’ll remove the additional code for the final version after the reviewer has given green light. The numbers and the references will automatically update.

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{lemma}{3}% just to show that the mid-lemma can go anywhere

Let's see the references:
lemma~\ref{bestlemma}, lemma~\ref{newlemma}, lemma~\ref{anotherlemma}.

\begin{lemma}\label{bestlemma}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}

%%% cut in final version
\let\savedthelemma\thelemma
\edef\thelemma{\thelemma.5}
%%% end cut here
\begin{lemma}\label{newlemma}
This is the added lemma.
\end{lemma}
%%% cut in final version
\let\thelemma\savedthelemma
\addtocounter{lemma}{-1}
%%% end cut here

\begin{lemma}\label{anotherlemma}
Another lemma.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After the cuts for the final version you'll get

[image]

If you have something like

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
```

so lemmas share the counter with theorems, use `thetheorem` instead of `thelemma` wherever it appears in the given code.

Should you need more mid-lemmas, you can avoid polluting the typescript so that minimal changes are needed for the final version.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

%%% cut for final version
%%% and remember to change
%%% \begin{lemma*}{...} --> \begin{lemma}
%%% \end{lemma*} --> \end{lemma}
\newenvironment{lemma*}[1]
 {%
  \let\savedthelemma\thelemma
  \edef\thelemma{\thelemma#1}%
  \lemma
 }
 {\endlemma\addtocounter{lemma}{-1}}
%\renewenvironment{lemma*}[1]{\lemma}{\endlemma}
%%% end cut

\begin{document}

\setcounter{lemma}{3}% just to show that the mid-lemma can go anywhere

Let's see the references:
lemma~\ref{bestlemma}, lemma~\ref{newlemma}, lemma~\ref{newlemmaagain}, lemma~\ref{anotherlemma}.

\begin{lemma}\label{bestlemma}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma*}{a}\label{newlemma}
This is the added lemma.
\end{lemma*}

\begin{lemma*}{b}\label{newlemmaagain}
This is the added lemma.
\end{lemma*}

\begin{lemma}\label{anotherlemma}
Another lemma.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

The same *caveat* as before applies if there are shared counters.

You can even test the final numbering by uncommenting the `\renewenvironment` line with no modifications to the body,
but for the really final version it's best that `lemma*` disappears.